# Formatting dates in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have the following code:

```
  <script>
$.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/OPEC/ORB.json?order=asc', function(json) {
    var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
      return [new Date(d[0]), d[1]]
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('chart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'OPEC Crude Oil Price',
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'OPEC',
        data: hiJson,
      }]
    });
});
```

Which prints a beautiful chart as follows:

[OPEC Crude Oil Price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NIHL.png)

But as you can see, the dates are not in the correct format. I am struggling to work out what is wrong?

All help much appreciated as always!

**UPDATE:**

So thanks to Holvar's comment I solved one problem, but now I have another on the same theme.

My code is as follows:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/BOE/IUAAAMIH.json?auth_token=pg6FBmvfQazVFdUgpqHz&start_date=2003-01-02&order=asc', function(json) {
    var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) {
      return [new Date(d[0]), d[1]]
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#interest').highcharts('chart', {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                          day: '%Y'
                      }  
      },            
      rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'UK Interest Rates',
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Interest Rate',
        data: hiJson,
      }]
    });
});
```

But this produces a chart without dates on the bottom. I'd like years from 2003-01-02. The chart looks like this

[UK Interest Rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7G8c.png)

I don't understand why it's not showing an annual date as in the solution to the initially posed question?!

You help is much appreciated!

Comment: Set the `xAxis.type` to `'datetime'`?

Comment: Oh dear... I feel a little silly now! Many thanks Halvor!!

Comment: @rupertbj hey buddy, it appears that it is loading only one of the dates from the returned json, in the `hiJson` array.

Comment: Yes I know @michaelStilson . seems it's only getting 1970, when i've requested only dates from 2003-01-02. I can't figure out why it's not responding properly. :(

Comment: @rupertbj Apologies, I worded my reply most poorly. I figured it out. Posting an potential answer soon.

Comment: Also, compliments to @HalvorStrand for commenting on how to achieve the desired time formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the way the data map is happening. The ending array contains multiple arrays, instead of an object with "x" and "y" properties. Try changing the initialization of the `hiJson` variable to something like:

`var hiJson = json.dataset.data.map(function(d) { return { x: new Date(d[0]), y: d[1] }; });`

That seems to be working on my local environment.

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear. :) Hey, perty please do us helping-out peoples a favor and mark our answers as "accepted" so, we can acquire the rep's. Many thanks!

Comment: I'd love to... but how? It's really not obvious how to... I've been looking for 20 mins!!

Comment: @rupertbj here you go, sir: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers thanks! and take care. :)

Comment: Ahhh... click the tick... got it! Thanks. @michaelstilson